# i did all the instruction on the documentation but i still get this error

Tags: python, flask

The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/user/<username>')
def show_user_profile(username):

    return 'User %s' % username
@app.route('/post/<int:post_id>')
def show_post(post_id):

    return 'Post %d' % post_id
@app.route('/path/<path:subpath>')
def show_subpath(subpath):

    return 'Subpath %s' % subpath
```

Comment: Well, *what* URL did you request?

Comment: i can't give u an answer because that's what I've found on the flask documentation and this my first day on web application so i don't have any clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not define a home route (`/`). Thus, when you start the app and navigate to the url as specified in the app setup instructions, the error posted above will be printed. Merely navigate to one of the other routes that you have declared:

```
/user/someting
/post/someval
/path/somepath
```

To avoid the message, create the route like so:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def home():
  return 'Welcome!'
```

Comment: @Hamza.Engineer The home route does not accept parameters. What error is currently occurring?

Comment: i added the home route to my code, but i get only the world 'welcome'

Comment: @Hamza.Engineer That is expected. Whatever is returned by the route will be displayed. What were you expecting?